# (Nativescript/Angular2) Keep user logged in

Tags: angular, nativescript

In the mobile application I'm developing, there is a login page. Once the user is logged in, he gets an access token which can be used for a few things but the access token is available for an hour. I know already how to renew it but is there a specific function which can be called so this operation is carried out automatically every hour ?

As for the login, for the moment, if I leave the application with the home button or the back button and I come back on the app, I'm still logged in but it's not the case if I kill the app (which I'd like to be the case). Is there anyone who knows how I could implement it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions to (not) aks and how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to take an alternative approach. What you’re trying to do is technically possible, but in general it’s a bad practice to run your app in the background unless it’s absolutely necessary. The code adds a lot of complexity, and a lot of users won’t give you permissions to run in the background anyways, since it’s a known way to drain your battery.

If you *really really* want to go down this route, you’re going to need to call the necessary iOS and Android APIs that allow your app to run in the background. There’s a [Cordova plugin for this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) that you could refer to, but you’re mostly going to have to write that code from scratch.

I would suggest one of two alternative approaches. Either 1) don’t expire your authentication tokens for app access, which may or may not be possible depending on your app, or 2) integrate the [NativeScript touch id plugin](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-touchid), which will simplify re-authentication for a good chunk of your users.

Comment: Since I don't have any Apple device, it'll be a little difficult to test that TouchID plugin ^^
Ok let's just say I don't want the app to run in the background. What about  refreshing the access token automatically ?

Comment: Is that okay if I put a setInterval in the constructor of the page ?

Comment: I think you’ll probably want to put the setInterval at a more global level so that it’s not tied to a specific page. But just know that when the user does not have your app open all code execution stops, so that setInterval won’t run in the background.